# Number of Solutions to Non-negative Integer Inequality

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I am trying to figure out the number of solutions to the equation:

$$x_1+x_2+...+x_r\leq n$$

where $x_i$, $i=1,2,...,r$ is non-negative and $n$ is some positive given integer.

I have already solved this for the case of an equality: this is just ${n+r-1\choose r-1}$ (following the traditional "stars and bars" method).

To solve for the number of solutions to the inequality, therefore, I thought that I could just solve for each case, i.e. when $x_1+x_2+...+x_r=n-1$, then $n-2$, etc. all the way down to $\sum x_i=1$. This would make my life easy, if it's true, as all I would have to do is just sum the combination term above with the varying values of $n$. However, given some scratchwork that I've done, I'm not so sure that this is the case.

Any suggestions as to why this might be true/false would be sincerely appreciated. If it is wrong, I just cannot find where the flaw in my thinking is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by taking the sum we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{k+r-1\choose r-1}={n+r\choose r}$$
where we used the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).
The same result can be obtained by enumerating the number of non-negative solutions of the equation
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_r+y= n.$$
where $y$ is a non-negative integer dummy variable.

Comment: I don't mean to sound dense, but that seems to be a confirmation of that about which I was doubtful.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Yes, summing is way to do it. But please read my edit.